# How are the middle two baryons in the baryon octet obtained?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

I understand that it has to be a combination of u,d and s such that it is antisymmetric in two indices, but how is this specific combination obtained?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248661/how-can-lambda0-and-sigma0-both-have-uds-quark-content).

Comment: Related : [Symmetry in terms of matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353986/symmetry-in-terms-of-matrices/355477#355477).

Answer (score 0):

[image: baryon octet] ,
so there is hardly any complication.

The Λ is an isosinglet uds, so disconnected from the $\Sigma^\pm $, uus, dds, in terms of isospin raising/lowering operators $I_\pm$, unlike the $\Sigma^0$ (also uds) which is gotten from these via these operators.

These two states are also orthogonal, as all isosinglets are orthogonal to isotriplets.

$\Lambda \sim (uds - dus)  \times ... \qquad \hbox{versus}  \qquad \Sigma^0\sim (uds+ dus) \times ... .$

For a formal appreciation read up on [SU(3) generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)).

The over-all baryon wavefunction has to be fully antisymmetric in its three constituents; and color completely antisymmetrizes the 3 quarks. So the combination flavor & spin &space pieces have to be symmetric in total.

Most good texts have the mixed-symmetry wavefunctions of these: they are thus long, messy expressions. Look at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/361022/66086).