# Octet and decuplet baryon wavefunction

Tags: wavefunction, standard-model, representation-theory, quarks, baryons

I read the octet and decuplet baryons symmetric and anti-symmetric wavefunction from 'Riazzudin and Fiazzudin's book. But I am little confused about the wavefunction of neutral sigma and Lambda baryon. What is the exact form of the wavefunction of baryons?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/762290/66086).

Comment: In some books, wavefunction of proton is presented like |p↑⟩=1/√6(2uud-udu-duu) and some book represent as |p↑⟩=-1/√6(2uud-udu-duu). What is the correct one that can be used if i want to apply an operator on wavefunction.

Comment: Hopefully you learned that an arbitrary phase is irrelevant.

Comment: In book like F.E. Close . I read the wavefunction for proton is  |p↑⟩= 1/√6(udu+duu-2uud) and for neutron, it is |n↑⟩=-1/√6(udd+dud-2ddu).  I am confused about the notation of signs used in the wave function.  Because I read in most of the books that negative sign come with proton wavefunction, not with neutron.  And same problem arises with Sigma and Cascade wavefunction.  It may be possible that my doubts are irrelevant but  please tell something.

Comment: What do you want to hear? That different books use different conventions and phases? What do you need the phases for? A reassurance that some careless authors muff irrelevant overall signs? Riazzudin and Fiazzudin's book is fine and consistent. Have you completely mastered tables 4 and 5 as the linked answer invites you to? Work the wavefunctions out by yourself; you surely know how to do that.