# Kaon decay on the quark level

Tags: particle-physics

How to make sense of a kaon decay $$K^+ \to \pi^0 + e^+ + \nu_e$$ if we take into account the quark structure of the kaon $K^+ = u \bar{s}$ and pion $\pi^0 = (u \bar{u} - d \bar{d})/\sqrt{2}$? Obviously, we have the weak decay of the $\bar{s}$ quark which produces $\bar{u}$. But, how do we get the extra $d \bar{d}$ quarks?

Comment: The quarks of the K must go into a W+.  The leptons come out of a  *W* +.  So consider  π  emission.

Answer (score 3):

The notation $\pi^0 = (u\bar{u} - d\bar{d})/\sqrt{2}$ means that the $\pi^0$ has equal probability of being either $u\bar{u}$ or $d\bar{d}$. It definitely doesn't mean they're tetraquarks!

They can be formed from a $u\bar{u}$ pair without having to consider the possibility of $d\bar{d}$, and vice-versa.

Comment: But u and d quarks have different mass...

Comment: So what? I don't see the relevance of that. Have a look at  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11039/73214

Comment: The pi0 made out of u quarks should be less massive than the one made of d quarks. But the pi0 has a well defined mass

Comment: The $\pi^0$ indeed has a well-defined mass. The $u\bar{u}$ and $d\bar{d}$ states do not have well-defined masses, though. You can't really say that one is heavier than the other.